Sub-Contractor Payment; “Salary”
Allright, im sort of new to this whole salary thing and im either stupid, being lied to or both. Im working my first job coming off hourly employment to now working as a sub contractor on a salary with a smaller company (boss, subcontractor1, subcontractor2 and me) I assumed the whole point of a salary is that there is a set amount of money you should make regardless of the hours worked.
I work fulltime and am payed fortnightly ($2000), My employment started on a Tuesday I worked that full week and a fortnight. I asked subcontractor2 who is close with the boss about my pay for the first week/fortnight and he told me id be paid $2800.
Im being paid through an ABN I was required to register for pre-employment which im also new to. I had to do an invoice to be paid which I hadnt done before so I called subcontractor1 and he told me to put on my invoice $200 a day for 14 days to match the said amount at $2800.
fast foward a fortnight to now and in abit of a sitch because the company which I wont disclose took a week off work (I worked 4 days of 10) and I get that I didnt work this week, but im also missing a big chunk of money because of this ($1200).
Now this week with them taking the week off work ive been told to also do the $200 a day for 4 days by them both. In which I did only work 4 days of a fortnight but this wasnt my fault.
Im kind just trying to get some outside perspectives/experience I enjoy the work and the lads are allright but something just seems odd.

What country or US State are you in (employment laws vary)? Do you have an employee agreement that specifies if you get paid annually, weekly, or daily? Is there an employee policy on paid or unpaid time off or furloughs?

Where are you? Rules for hourly employees differ from place to place. Also, what does your contract say -- normally hourly workers are paid only for hours actually worked, possibly plus explicit paid holidays, and if the business shuts down for a few days other than those you aren't working and don't get paid.

sub contractor on a salary - this seems contradictory. If you're a contractor, you're not being paid a salary.

Sounds like a daily rate, not a salary.

You believe you agreed to be paid $2000 fortnightly, that is to say, 26 times per year, regardless of how much you work.
You and the company have a different understanding of this arrangement. You think that the full salary should be paid fortnightly regardless of days off, vacation, holidays and sick days. The company seems to think that you are not paid for the days off, vacation, holidays and sick days, essentially docking you $200 per weekday not worked.
As a commenter mentioned, the company is treating it like a day rate of $200, and if you don't work for whatever reason, you get $0 for that weekday.
You can say, "I didn't agree to a day rate of $200, I expected to receive $2000 every fortnight. Is that not your understanding?"
